# Performance issue with logback with slf4j API

Tags: java, performance, logging

I am using windows machine to get performance results for logback + slf4j

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.Level;

public class LogPerformanceAnalyser {
    private static final Logger LOG =
            LoggerFactory.getLogger(LogPerformanceAnalyser.class);

    public LogPerformanceAnalyser() {
        ((ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger) LOG).setLevel(Level.ERROR);
    }

    public long getTimeWithCheck() {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
            if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
                LOG.debug("This log is {} check", "with");
            }
        }
        return System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
    }

    public long getTimeWithoutCheck() {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
            LOG.debug("This log is {} check", "without");
        }
        return System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
    }
}
```

Note -
1. debug is off
2. Running 10 times to get average result.

Performance Results are :

```
Total Time getTimeWithoutCheck: 26900 ms
Total Time getTimeWithCheck : 22536 ms
```

Result is that placing the check before logging saved ~3.5 sec for 21.7 billion logs.

If i changed Logger as non static :

```
private final Logger LOG = 
        LoggerFactory.getLogger(LogPerformanceAnalyser.class);
```

and I get the following:

```
Total Time getTimeWithoutCheck: 37095 ms
Total Time getTimeWithCheck : 47006 ms
```

Can anyone explain the this?

Comment: java JIT + branch prediction might do the trick.

Answer (score 9):

First of all, you need correct benchmarks. In Java world [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) is the de-facto standard of benchmarking.

Benchmarks:

```
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
@State(Scope.Thread)
public class LogBench {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LogBench.class);

    private final Logger localLog = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LogBench.class);


    @Benchmark
    public long baseline() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void getTimeWithCheck() {
        if (LOG.isTraceEnabled()) {
            LOG.trace("This log is {} check", "with");
        }
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void getTimeWithoutCheck() {
        LOG.trace("This log is {} check", "without");
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void getTimeWithCheckBenchLocal() {
        if (localLog.isTraceEnabled()) {
            localLog.trace("This log is {} check", "with");
        }
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void getTimeWithoutCheckLocal() {
        localLog.trace("This log is {} check", "without");
    }
}
```

I changed debug to trace to avoid possible effects of the cast.

And the results

```
    Benchmark                                     Mode   Samples        Score  Score error    Units
    o.o.j.s.LogBench.baseline                     avgt         3        0.539        0.047    ns/op
    o.o.j.s.LogBench.getTimeWithCheck             avgt         3        1.030        0.083    ns/op
    o.o.j.s.LogBench.getTimeWithCheckLocal        avgt         3        1.637        0.571    ns/op
    o.o.j.s.LogBench.getTimeWithoutCheck          avgt         3        1.140        0.112    ns/op
    o.o.j.s.LogBench.getTimeWithoutCheckLocal     avgt         3        1.628        0.311    ns/op
```

You can see, conditional check is useless here, but static version is 1.6x times faster than local. Let's start exploring with the difference between getTimeWithCheckLocal and getTimeWithCheck.

#### Static LOG assembly

```
Beginning of getTimeWithCheck:
[Verified Entry Point]
  0x00007f06b920b440: mov    DWORD PTR [rsp-0x14000],eax
  0x00007f06b920b447: push   rbp
  0x00007f06b920b448: sub    rsp,0x20           ;*synchronization entry
                                            ; - org.openjdk.jmh.samples.LogBench::getTimeWithoutCheck@-1 (line 65)

execution:
  0x00007f06b920b44c: movabs r10,0x76d8bdfd0    ;   {oop(a 'ch/qos/logback/classic/Logger')}
  0x00007f06b920b456: mov    r11d,DWORD PTR [r10+0x28] ;*getfield loggerContext
  0x00007f06b920b45a: mov    r9d,DWORD PTR [r12+r11*8+0x60]  ;*getfield turboFilterList
  0x00007f06b920b45f: mov    r8d,DWORD PTR [r12+r9*8+0x10] ;*getfield array
...
```

#### Nonstatic LOG assembly

```
[Verified Entry Point]
  0x00007f1c592111e0: mov    DWORD PTR [rsp-0x14000],eax
  0x00007f1c592111e7: push   rbp
  0x00007f1c592111e8: sub    rsp,0x30           ;*synchronization entry
                                            ; - org.openjdk.jmh.samples.LogBench::getTimeWithoutCheckLocal@-1 (line 77)

  0x00007f1c592111ec: mov    r11d,DWORD PTR [rsi+0xc]  ;*getfield localLog
  0x00007f1c592111f0: mov    r10d,DWORD PTR [r12+r11*8+0x8] ; implicit exception: dispatches to 0x00007f1c59211281
  0x00007f1c592111f5: cmp    r10d,0xf80154ad    ;   {metadata('ch/qos/logback/classic/Logger')}
  0x00007f1c592111fc: jne    0x00007f1c5921123c

execution:
  0x00007f1c592111fe: lea    r8,[r12+r11*8]     ;*invokeinterface debug
  0x00007f1c59211202: mov    ecx,DWORD PTR [r8+0x28]  ;*getfield loggerContext
```

You can notice that in the second experiment JIT has to perform an additional load of the Logger field value: `lea    r9,[r12+r10*8]`.

Let's run benchmark again with the perfasm profiler

```
0.04%    0.04%  │↗  0x00007f6c25229320: mov    r10d,DWORD PTR [r8+0xc]  ;*getfield localLog
                ││                                                ; - org.openjdk.jmh.samples.LogBench::getTimeWithoutCheckLocal@1 (line 77)
                ││                                                ; - org.openjdk.jmh.samples.generated.LogBench_getTimeWithoutCheckLocal_jmhTest::getTimeWithoutCheckLocal_avgt_jmhStub@14 (line 163)
6.80%    7.29%  ││  0x00007f6c25229324: mov    r11d,DWORD PTR [r12+r10*8+0x8]
                ││                                                ; implicit exception: dispatches to 0x00007f6c252294a5
         0.02%  ││  0x00007f6c25229329: cmp    r11d,0xf80197b1    ;   {metadata(&apos;ch/qos/logback/classic/Logger&apos;)}
                ││  0x00007f6c25229330: jne    0x00007f6c2522939b
                ││  0x00007f6c25229332: lea    r9,[r12+r10*8]     ;*invokeinterface debug
                ││  0x00007f6c25229336: mov    ecx,DWORD PTR [r9+0x28]  ;*getfield loggerContext
```

As you can see this additional loading isn't free. This is because a lot of ways to change final variable exists, so it is unsafe to perform this optimization for fields.

As experimental feature jvm has an special option `-XX:+TrustFinalNonStaticFields`, it must be used with `-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions`. If you run the benchmark with this option you'll see another results:

```
Benchmark                            Mode  Cnt  Score   Error  Units
LogBench.baseline                    avgt    3  2.124 ± 0.907  ns/op
LogBench.getTimeWithCheck            avgt    3  0.695 ± 0.231  ns/op
LogBench.getTimeWithCheckBenchLocal  avgt    3  1.608 ± 0.140  ns/op
LogBench.getTimeWithoutCheck         avgt    3  0.675 ± 0.075  ns/op
LogBench.getTimeWithoutCheckLocal    avgt    3  1.613 ± 0.176  ns/op
```

The results is strange, althrough there is no additional load of local variables now, inlining is broken, asm code contains direct calls:

```
0x00007f2355205d33: call   0x00007f2355046020  ; OopMap{off=120}
                                            ;*invokespecial filterAndLog_1
```

## Conclusions

- JVM can't trust final fields, so it has to load it from memory every time in benchmark (but it wouldn't be a problem in 99.999999% applications)
- JVM has [experimental option](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/hotspot/file/87ee5ee27509/src/share/vm/ci/ciField.cpp#l193) `TrustFinalNonStaticFields` which seems to be quite unstable because it breaks CHA optimization

Comment: Good analysis, but wrong conclusions. All these have nothing to do with null checks. Non-static version just needs to perform an extra field load.

Comment: @apangin, Oh, I thought it is little bit strange. But I still in doubt, loading `mov    r10d,DWORD PTR [r8+0xc]` for `cmp` seems to be much slower than loading field `r11d,DWORD PTR [rsi+0xc]`, isn't it?

Comment: @apangin, Oh, got it. You are right, still wonder why it doesn't use Logger pointer in r11 further

Comment: It can't, because the benchmark loop contains a volatile load which acts as a barrier. So each benchmark iteration loads `localLog` field and checks its type again and again.

Comment: @SerCe, Thanks for your efforts but results are different. Can you look my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The results are more or less consistent with the assumption that a field access contributes 10000 ms to the total run time. Without the check you have this overhead once, with the check you have it twice.

It is still surprising that the difference is so much.

Comment: It is recommended that we should not use static logger. http://wiki.apache.org/commons/Logging/StaticLog
http://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#declared_static
http://slf4j.org/faq.html#logging_performance   So i tried for the same but i am confused that should i use if(Log.isDebugEnabled) before log.debug.

Comment: In most cases you don't need this extra check. It is only useful if you guard several log statements at once or if parameter expressions are expensive to evaluate.

Comment: @Ravi "we" should not use static logging references if a moron just added logging in a hierarchie above us and thus initialization occurred prior to our code.